# Rename entity for OData service generated via Referenced CDS views?

Tags: odata, sapui5, cds, sap-gateway

I implemented some CDS views with associations on a SAP NETWEAVER 7.5 SP 19 (09/2020) system.

I used in the SEGW transaction the reference by data source feature to automatically create the ODATA types and associations from the CDS views and add them to a existing SEGW ODATA project.

Then I use that ODATA service in a SAPUI5 app.

Here is one of the guides i used: https://www.saplearners.com/create-odata-service-abap-cds-views-segw/

**CDS view**

The CDS view is named like **/ID/VIEW_NAME_CDS**.

The associations are renamed with *as* and get an underscore before the name. The name is then **_assication_name**. The underscore seems to be a convention by SAP to make the navigation property readable.

**Result**

In the SEGW project the wizard creates a Entity Type with the name: **x**id**x**view_name_cds**Type**
Every slash will be replaced by an **x** and at the end **Type** will be added.

The navigation property is named **to_assication_name**.

The association gets a name like **assoc_0D6ADC4B279EADE543738376111F7216**.

**Goal**

I want to change the name of the entity types, associations and navigation properties because I want some readable names in the sapui5 app

Clarification 2020/11/30: The name should also be changed in the SEGW transaction itself so that they are the same in SEGW and SAPUI5 because some months in the future annother developer will not think that I changed the names in the MPC_EXT class. At least I wouldn't think of that. :-)

Is this possible with annotations in the CDS view? Or any other way?

**Example**

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZTEST'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: 'A test'
define view /ABC/SYSTEM_RESULT_CDS as
  select from system                        as system
  association [1..*] to /abc/s_mon_result   as _monitoring_results on _monitoring_results.system_id    = $projection.system_id
{
    key system.system_id,
        system.name,
        _monitoring_results
}
group by system.system_id
```

**Entity Type**: xabcxsystem_result_cdsType

This a mix of camel case style and snake case. Not very readable.

**Navigation Properties**: to_monitoring_results

Is ok but i would like to have the oportunity to rename it.

**Association**: assoc_0D6ADC4B279EADE543738376111F7216

Not readable. Only if you click on it you see the 2 entities to which the association belongs.

Comment: You can rename your nav properties in the CDS view. Expose it via `_monitoring_results as MonitoringResults` which will result in `toMonitoringResults`. The association name is unreadable, but do you really ever use it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to redefine `DEFINE` method of `MPC_EXT` class, the runtime artifact after service generation:

```
 super->define( ).

 DATA: lo_entity_type TYPE REF TO /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_entity_typ,
       lo_entity_set   TYPE REF TO /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_entity_set,
       lo_property    TYPE REF TO /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_property.

 " for entity type
 lo_entity_type = model->get_entity_type( 'C_Cfd_UsageType' ).
 lo_entity_type->set_name( iv_name = 'CFDUsage' ).

 " for association
 lo_entity_type = model->get_association( 'C_CFD_Assoc' ).
 lo_entity_set->set_name( iv_name = 'CFDAssociation' ).

 " for entity set
 lo_entity_set = model->get_entity_set( 'C_Cfd_Usage' ).
 lo_entity_set->set_name( iv_name = 'CFD' ).
```

After that new names will be reflected in the service $metadata:

[image]

Comment: Ok, that is one possibility. The name in the SEGW transaction won't change or? In the line `"model->get_association( 'C_CFD_Assoc)"` you forgot some characters `');` I still would prefer annotations. Do you know a way?

Comment: `The name in the SEGW transaction won't change or?` no, not in SEGW, but it should be fine for UI5

Comment: `you forgot some characters ')` indeed, I did. Corrected, thx

Comment: I added a clarification to my goal in the first post but thank you for your answer. It is good to know and maybe other devlopers need it.